# Next TS MongoDb Error Post Request failed

Tags: mongodb, next.js

I'm just starting out learning mongodb and following the official tutorial on YT and ran into an error when trying to connect and run a function.
This is my code:

```
"use client"
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import * as Realm from "realm-web"

export default function Home() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const FetchProducts = async()=>{
      const REALM_APP_ID = "{myAppId}";
      const app = new Realm.App({id:REALM_APP_ID});
      const credentials = Realm.Credentials.anonymous();
      try{
        const user = await app.logIn(credentials);
        const allProducts = await user.functions.getAllProducts();
        setProducts(allProducts);
        console.log(allProducts);
      }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    FetchProducts();

  },[])

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      {products && products.map(product =>(
        <p key={product['_id']} className='text-gray-200'>{product['name']}</p>
      ))}
    </main>
  )
}
```

This code displays all the items within the YT tutorial but I am getting an error of:

```
Error: Request failed (POST https://us-east-1.aws.realm.mongodb.com/api/client/v2.0/app/products-pqfns/functions/call): function not found: 'getAllProducts' (status 404)
    at MongoDBRealmError.fromRequestAndResponse (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/realm-web/dist/bundle.dom.es.js:2871:24)
    at async Fetcher.fetch (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/realm-web/dist/bundle.dom.es.js:3034:23)
    at async Fetcher.fetchJSON (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/realm-web/dist/bundle.dom.es.js:3051:26)
    at async FetchProducts (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./src/app/page.tsx:25:37)
```

Also getting a Post Error. Doesn't anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.
PS- I have created the function `getAllProducts()` within atlas

edit:
I expanded this error and it says this:
`{error: "no matching rule found", error_code: "NoMatchingRuleFound",…}`

Comment: You can also do handle this logic in the api routes if you don't mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing was wrong with the code, to fix this issue I had to do a device sync which was not shown in the tutorial. This fixed my error and I am receiving the data.

Answer (score 0):

Your passing a string instead of the actual Realm ID

Try saving your Realm ID to .env.local and then pass it directly to REALM_APP_ID as process.env.REALM_APP_ID instead of doing this "{myAppId}". It's safer that way.

```
const REALM_APP_ID = process.env.REALM_APP_ID;
```

---

.env.local

```
REALM_APP_ID = "actual id here";
```

Comment: I pass  in the actual ID there as im only testing it out, I only put "{myAppId}" so that I dont paste my actual key here